# Mock a large Partial Class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, partial-classes

I want to make a unit test for a Controller method that have 3 database calls. But each database call is done by asking a large Partial Class file, which name is DAL. The Dal class have like 70 methods! Do I have to make a Interface with 70 methods, that the DAL class can use; so I can switch it with a mock? Or is there a better solution on how I can mock this DAL class?

Comment: If you go the interface way, you could make several small interfaces and let the DAL implemenet all of them. This way you can "categorize" the dependencies - and the unit tests.

Comment: Instead of using a Partial, why don't you derive from the DAL class and implement your own specific interface for your Controller methods. That way you have access to both worlds but you can still mock the parts you want without worrying about the DAL class.

Comment: With for instance Moq, you only need to mock the methods you call. So you could use Visual Studio to extract your giant interface and then only mock the methods you expect to be called in your test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having one huge class with 70 methods is bound to create problems like this. Without having to refactor your DAL class, in smaller repositories for example, you could create smaller interfaces with the few methods you need for each controller and have your DAL class implement many of these smaller interfaces. You could then mock only the interfaces you want, and have your controller depend on this interface too.

It could look something like:

```
interface A {
    void DoAThing();
}
interface B {
    void DoBThing();
}
class Mock : A {
    public void DoAThing() {
        //fake it till you make it       
    }
}
class DAL : A, B {
    //Way too many methods here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a free mocking library for C# called Moq (mock-u or mock), this can be got through Nuget. It allows very powerful mocking control using lambda expressions and various verification calls. You do not need to specify any more method definitions than you need, and the behaviour of each method can be completely changed per call.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

I can personally vouch for Moq as being amazing.

Comment: Yeah, I second Moq as the one to go for (there are loads of different mocking frameworks available, but I definitely like Moq best). BTW I think you should add to your answer something about how to automatically extract an interface from a class using Visual Studio via `Edit | Refactor | Extract Interface`).

Comment: Thanks. I will check out Moq when I get time.